# Acessar banco de dados no OpenShift

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, openshift

Fiz deploy de um projeto no `OpenShift`, usei uma *cartridge* pra criar um banco `Mysql` logo após a criação do banco aparecem essas informações:

> MySQL 5.5 database added. Please make note of these credentials:
>
> Root User: adminhtK8LZq Root Password: shKekKGKhHEH Database Name:
>   oraculo
>
> Connection URL:
>   mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
>
> You can manage your new MySQL database by also embedding phpmyadmin.
>   The phpmyadmin username and password will be the same as the MySQL
>   credentials above.

Porém quando configuro meu `hibernate.cfg` com esses dados o banco não é criado no `OpenShift`.

Hibernate.cfg:

```
<!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/oraculo </property>
        <property name="connection.username">adminhtK8LZq</property>
        <property name="connection.password">shKekKGKhHEH</property>
        ...
```

Tenho que passar algum valor no lugar dessa URL, já tentei passar o ip que aparece no `phpMyAdmin` porém não funcionou.

Comment: Alguma razao para a pass dada pelo Openshift e a pass no hibernate.cfg serem diferentes?

Comment: E por que o hibernate criaria o banco? Ele só é capaz de criar ou atualizar as tabelas em um **banco já existente**. Para tanto, use `<property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</property>`, ou `update` no lugar do *create*.

Comment: O banco já existe e eu estou usando o create

Comment: Você consegue acessar o seu cartridge via ssh e verificar se consegue se conectar usando essas credenciais?

Comment: Consigo sim, eu acesso usando essas credenciais pelo phpMyAdmin também

Comment: vc ja chegou colocar ip e porta que tão la no phpmyadmin ali no mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/ e fazer o deploy de novo ?

Comment: Tentei sim, porém continua na mesma. Vou fazer mais um teste.

Comment: Acabei de tentar novamente e nada, quando acesso a URL que faria a consulta o banco não é criado. URL: `http://sistemaoraculo-projetounimed.rhcloud.com/usuario/usuarios/consultar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu trabalho com OpenShift. Vou te explicar o que ocorre e como eu costumo trabalhar nesse tipo de coisa.

O openshift tem algumas variáveis para facilitar sua vida. *$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST*, *$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT* e outras estão definidas lá no openshift.

Abaixo tem um exemplo de como eu faço para recuperar as variáveis e conectar usando JDBC:

```
this.openShiftDbHost = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
this.openShiftDbPort = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
this.openShiftDbUser = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
this.openShiftDbPassword = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");
conexao =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+this.openShiftDbHost+":"+this.openShiftDbPort+"/mydb?user="+this.openShiftDbUser+"&password="+this.openShiftDbPassword);
```

No caso do hibernate eu faço a seguinte coniguração:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}" />
<property name="username" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}" />
<property name="password" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}" />
```

Comment: Vou tentar aqui

Comment: Fiz da maneira que voce falou porém ainda não funcionou, quando tento acessar a URL dessa API que faz uma consulta no banco, o mesmo não é criado. `http://sistemaoraculo-projetounimed.rhcloud.com/usuario/usuario/1`

Comment: Só uma dúvida, eu tenho que trocar os valores, por exemplo: `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` para o caminho do banco?

Comment: Não precisa mudar nada não cara. Para acessar o banco fora da aplicação é necessário usar o PhpMyAdmin fornecido no OpenShift.

Comment: Tentei e mesmo assim não funcionou, outra coisa estranha que notei, quando faço alterações na pagina index.html e dou commit nada muda, porem se eu clono o projeto ele vem com as alterações feitas, de primeira instância achei que o commit/push não estava dando certo.

Comment: Problema resolvido, o commit não estava funcionando mesmo